# Codeigniter image cropping is not working

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1 on localhost.
I am trying to crop images but cropping is not working. Only resize working. So i enabled `Gd2` php extension.

**1.**

```
public function do_crop($filename)
{
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $source_path =  'uploads/' . $filename;
    $target_path =  'uploads/thumb/'.$filename;

    $config = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $source_path,
        'new_image' => $target_path,
        'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
        'x_axis' => 300,
        'y_axis' => 100,
    );
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
}
```

**Image size = 1000X700**

The output result is same as original image size `1000X700`

**2.**

```
public function do_crop($filename)
    {
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $source_path =  'uploads/' . $filename;
        $target_path =  'uploads/thumb/'.$filename;

        $config = array(
            'image_library' => 'gd2',
            'source_image' => $source_path,
            'new_image' => $target_path,
            'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
            'width' => 300,
            'height' => 300,
            'x_axis' => 350,
             'y_axis' => 50
        );
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    }
```

**Image size = 1000X700**

And the 2nd example only resize (`300x300`) the image but not cropped.

Comment: Can you please explain more for better understanding

Comment: What you want to do exactly.

Comment: For emaple if image size 1000X700 then i want to crop `300x50` from original image size . I don't want to resize. @MuhammadUsman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$config = array(
'source_image' => $upload_path.$image_data['file_name'],
'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
'width' => 220,
'height' => 150,
'x_axis' => 350,
'y_axis' => 50
);
$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->crop();
```

For more details Please [See Here](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Image_resize_and_crop_in_Codeigniter-gsn)
For More Info [Check Here](http://kennykee.com/138/codeigniter-resize-and-crop-image-to-fit-container-div-example/)

Comment: Let me know if face any problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325106/how-to-crop-image-in-codeigniter

Comment: A Good Library At Github https://jenssegers.com/31/codeigniter-resizing-and-cropping-images-on-the-fly

Comment: See This Also http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-image-manipulation-tutorial @mehur

Comment: Working . Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome Buddy Glad to help ;)

Comment: @Mehur http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html#CI_Image_lib::clear

Comment: Thank you. Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238671/ajax-upload-not-working-codeigniter ?